# How to select multiple non-contigous columns from a list into another dataframe in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am working on `Ipython` and `Spark` and I have a `RDD` from which I form a `list`. Now from this `list` I want to form a `dataframe` which has multiple columns from parent `list` but these columns are not contiguous. I wrote this but it seems to be working wrong:

```
list1 = rdd.collect()
columns_num = [1,8,11,17,21,24]
df2 = [list[i] for i in columns_num]
```

The above code only selects 6 rows, with only column 1 data, from parent `list` and forms the new `dataframe` with those 6 columns 1 data.

How can I form a new `dataframe` with multiple not contiguous columns from another `list`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", 1, 2, 4.0, "foo"), ("b", 3, 4, 5.0, "bar")])
columns_num = [0, 3]

df = rdd.toDF()
df2 = df.select(*(df.columns[i] for i in columns_num))
df2.show()

##  +---+---+
##  | _1| _4|
##  +---+---+
##  |  a|4.0|
##  |  b|5.0|
##  +---+---+
```

or like this:

```
df = rdd.map(lambda row: [row[i] for i in columns_num]).toDF()
df.show()

##  +---+---+
##  | _1| _4|
##  +---+---+
##  |  a|4.0|
##  |  b|5.0|
##  +---+---+
```

On a side not you should never collect data just to reshape. In the best case scenario it will be slow, in the worst case scenario it will simply crash.

Comment: I am glad to hear that and thanks for accepting the answer. Still, I would be grateful I could provide an example which fails with the first approach if you have time :)

Comment: Theres one thing I noticed. This is not forming a pandas dataframe right? How can I form a pandas dataframe?

Comment: No it doesn't. You want a local data structure? You can simply call `toPandas()` on a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

With Optimus this is really easy. You just need to install it with:

```
 pip install optimuspyspark
```

Then you import it (it will start Spark for you):

```
import optimus as op
```

Let's create the DF:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", 1, 2, 4.0, "foo"), ("b", 3, 4, 5.0, "bar")])
df = rdd.toDF()
```

And start the transformer:

```
transformer = op.DataFrameTransformer(df)
```

And select your columns

```
df_new = transformer.select_idx([0,2]).df
```

And you have it now:

```
df_new.show()

+---+---+
| _1| _3|
+---+---+
|  a|  2|
|  b|  4|
+---+---+
```